# How to show that a set operation is associative?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have a problem to solve, that goes like that:
(roughly translated from German)

$G$ is a set with associative composition. $e$ is the neutral element, so that for each $g\in G$, $e\cdot g=g\cdot e=g$. From the power set $\mathcal P(G)$ of $G$, we define the composition:

$$\mathcal P(G)\times\mathcal P(G)\to\mathcal P(G)$$

$$(A,B)\mapsto A\cdot B :=\{g\in G|\exists a\in A,b\in B : g = a\cdot b\}$$

Show that
a) this operation is associative
b) there is a neutral element in that operation. Which one?

I've already tried several approaches to that problem, but I struggle to understand what is the "composition" and what then should be associative? Wikipedia says "function composition is the pointwise application of one function to the result of another to produce a third function", which I imagine refers to $f(g(x))$ for example. But how does that apply here?

Thank you very much for your hints.

J.

Answer (score 1):

The composition is the operation which takes in a pair of subsets $A$ and $B$ of $G$ and spits out the set $$A*B=\{g\in G: \exists a\in A, b\in B\mbox{ such that } g=a*b\}$$ (using "$*$" for the binary operations). The problem is asking you to show that this operation is associative - that is, $(A*B)*C=A*(B*C)$ for every $A, B, C\subseteq G$ (note: "$\subseteq G$" means the same thing as "$\in\mathcal{P}(G)$," and might be easier to think about) - and has a neutral element - that is, there is some $E\subseteq G$ such that $A*E=E*A=A$ for all $A\subseteq G$.

Note that there's a bit of abuse of notation going around: we're using the same symbol, "$*$," to refer to the binary operation on $G$ and the induced "composition" operation on $\mathcal{P}(G)$. Technically we should really use a different symbol, but meh.

---

Before tackling this problem, if you're still confused it might help to play with some more concrete problems. For instance:

- Suppose $G$ is the set of all integers, and $*$ (on $G$) is the operation of addition. What is $$\mbox{$\{$evens$\}*\{$odds$\}$?}$$
- Let $A\subseteq G$. Knowing nothing about $A$ or $G$, what can we say about $\emptyset*A$?
- Suppose additionally $G$ has inverses - for every $a\in G$ there is a $b\in G$ such that $a*b=b*a=e$. What can you say about $G*A$ for $A\subseteq G$ *nonempty*?

Comment: To begin, thank you for your very complete answer and for your leads on how to solve the problem. I will try now to answer your problems: 1. I would say the answer is G, because the addition of the sets of evens and odds gives the complete set of integers. 2. I would say the addition between A and the empty set gives A, and this addition belongs therefore also to G. 3. I would conclude, that for every x belonging to A + G, there exists a y belonging to G so that x * y = e. Also, in the case of A = G, wouldnt it be that A + G would be the empty set because the inverses would cancel each other?

Comment: @Julien You are misunderstanding the definition. Let's look at the first question: suppose I take an even number and an odd number, and I add them. What sort of number do I get? Now, what is $\{$evens$\}*\{$odds$\}$?

Comment: An odd? Yeah I confused addition with union there.

Comment: So for your first question,  the answer would be the set of odd integers?

Answer (score 1):

The term composition is slightly misleading here (which might be a translation issue).

What you are dealing with is not **function** composition (which is the "default" thing we think about when we say composition. It is the composition of **elements** in a set, i.e. you are given a mapping that, for every pair of elements $x,y\in G$, gives you the element $x\cdot y$. This is more commonly refered to as "operation".

Given that operation, you then define a **new** operation on the set $\mathcal P(G)$.

What you must do now is prove that, for any three subsets of $G$ (i.e., elements of $\mathcal P(G)$, the set

$$(A\cdot B)\cdot C$$

is equal to the set $$A\cdot (B\cdot C)$$

Comment: The term isn't really misleading in my opinion - each $A\subseteq G$ is viewed as the function on $\mathcal{P}(G)$ given by "$B\mapsto A*B$." Then $*$ is exactly composition of functions. This may seem tautologous, but it's not - the fact that this is a composition of functions is **precisely** the fact that the original "$*$" was associative! So in some sense it's exactly the right term.